# ANTLR - How to accept double quotes inside double quoted string while parsing

Tags: antlr4

I've developed a grammar which parse a specific file. I need the grammar to parse strings if it is enclosed with double quotes("some text") and I did this. The part I'm looking for is, I need to handle all the cases where a string itself contains some double quotes in it with the escape character.

Also when it comes to backslashes, it must accept the double backslashes and convert it into single
Please refer the following cases

"Some text" -> valid -> expected is -> **Some text**

"Some \"text\"" -> valid -> expected is -> **Some "text"**

"Some text and back slash\\" -> valid -> expected is -> **Some text and back slash\**

"Some "text"" -> invalid input -> since there is not escape character for inside double quote

"Some text and back slash\" -> invalid input -> since there is not escape character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since so many languages have dealt with this sort of thing before, a great resource is the ANTLR grammars page [ANTLR Grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4).

I just pulled up the JSON grammar, removed the Unicode stuff, and this is their solution.  It should do just what you asked for.  If you want Unicode, you could pull it in as-is from the JSON grammar.

```
STRING
   : '"' (ESC | SAFECODEPOINT)* '"'
   ;

fragment ESC
   : '\\' (["\\/bfnrt])
   ;

fragment SAFECODEPOINT
   : ~ ["\\\u0000-\u001F]
   ;
```

The `ESC` fragment is what will recognize you \” sequence and make it part of the string (It’ll also allow esacping / \b, \f, \n, \r, \t and \.  You may not want all of these, but you’ll probably, at least want \ which will allow a user to place a literal \ in their string. The `SAFECODEPOINT` fragment excludes ASCII range characters you’d not want to allow in your string (including the terminating “, and the \ that begins an escape sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mike. This is what I was using earlier. But this rule is not parsing the following input as expected. 
"Some text \"text\"" -> this is parsed as -> Some text \"text\ 
It skips the last double quote.

Comment: Check your logic to pull the string out of the token.  The Token text will include the opening and closing "s (they are part of the lexer rule), so it looks like you're trying to strip them.   If I run this through the tokenizer I get: [@0,0:19='"Some text \"text\""',<STRING>,1:0]. (that's using grun with the -tokens option.  ANTLR is pulling in the trailing "